# Salvar dados do formulário no banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel-5.4

Estou tendo um grande dificuldade ao tentar criar um formulário no *Laravel 5.4*. O formulário aparece normal, mas quando eu clico no botão, a página se recarrega e os dados não são salvos no banco!

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'users')) }}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
    {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
    {{ Form::email('email', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('password', 'Senha') }}
    {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('nerd_level', 'User Level') }}
    {{ Form::select('nerd_level', array('0' => 'Nomal', '1' => 'Admin'), null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>

{{ Form::submit('Create the User!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Controllers**:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
 use App\User;     
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
 use Session;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
 class UserController extends BaseController
 {
public function index()
{
    // get all the users
    $users = User::all();

    // load the view and pass the users
    return view('users.index')
        ->with('users', $users);
}
public function create()
{
    // load the create form (app/views/users/create.blade.php)
    return view('users.create');
}
public function store()
{
    // validate
    // read more on validation at http://laravel.com/docs/validation
    $rules = array(
        'name'       => 'required',
        'email'      => 'required|email',
        'password'   => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('users/create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {
        // store
        $user = new User;
        $user->name       =  Input::get('name');
        $user->email      = Input::get('email');
        $user->password   = bcrypt('password');
        $user->save();
        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!');
        return Redirect::to('users');
    }
  }
 }
```

**Routes**:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'auth.admin']], function () {
  // Minhas rotas da administração aqui
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Coloque as rotas e o controller na sua pergunta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `form::open` dentro do `array` configuração da chave `url` coloque assim:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/users/store')) }}
```

ou pela configuração da chave `route` passando o nome da rota:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('users.store'))) }}
```

que é a rota `resource` criada por você nas configurações de rota, o problema que anteriormente está indo para a rota `index` e por isso não acontecia nada.

---

A tabelas de criação de rotas resource do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) segue uma nomenclatura e dada como exemplo logo abaixo:

[*Actions Handled By Resource Controller*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

```
+--------+-------------------------+---------+----------------+
|  Verb  |           Path          | Action  |    Route Name  |
+--------+-------------------------+---------+----------------+
| GET    | /photo                  | index   | photo.index    |
| GET    | /photo/create           | create  | photo.create   |
| POST   | /photo                  | store   | photo.store    |
| GET    | /photo/{photo}          | show    | photo.show     |
| GET    | /photo/{photo}/edit     | edit    | photo.edit     |
| PUT    | /PATCH/photo/{photo}    | update  | photo.update   |
| DELETE | /photo/{photo}          | destroy | photo.destroy  | 
+--------+-------------------------+---------+----------------+
```

onde `photo` seria o nome dado por você nas rotas `resource` de um determinado `Controller`.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)
- [Opening A Form - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form)

Comment: Agora deu certo! valeu pela ajuda!